# jQuery "wrapAll" duplicate content

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I have an issue with the **wrapAll** jQuery function.
I'm creating a WordPress theme, and I need the menu elements to be slightly different on desktop than they are on mobile. Long story short, I need to wrap some menu items into a div.

So here is the HTML code involved, before I call my jQuery function (I voluntarily not include upper ul and li parents to simplify the question):

```
<li id="menu-item-124" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://foo.bar">Arbitrage</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-132" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://foo.bar">Enseignement</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-82" class="sub__cat last__right el--right no-href menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-82"><a href="#">Multimédia</a>
    <ul  class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://foo.bar">Photos &#038; vidéos</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="http://foo.bar">Téléchargements</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I did is adding a class (**el--right**) to every menu item I want to be wrapped. I check if **elements__right** div exists to avoid creating it several times, and then I wrap all the **el--right** items to a **elements--right** div.

Then I have this function (**jq** is for noConflict) which is called on document(ready):

```
function desktopMenu() {
    
    if ( jq(window).width() > 1365 ) {
                
        if ( jq('.elements__right').length > 0 ) {

        } else {
            
            jq('.el--right').wrapAll('<div class="elements__right"> </div>');
            
        }
 }
```

So the result I want is the following:

```
<div class="elements__right"> 
    <li id="menu-item-124" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://foo.bar">Arbitrage</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-132" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://foo.bar">Enseignement</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="sub__cat last__right el--right no-href menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-82"><a href="#">Multimédia</a>
        <ul  class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://foo.bar">Photos &#038; vidéos</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="http://foo.bar">Téléchargements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

But the content is duplicated. Strangely, it duplicated without menu items' ID:

```
<div class="elements__right"> 
    <li id="menu-item-124" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://foo.bar">Arbitrage</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-132" class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://foo.bar">Enseignement</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="sub__cat last__right el--right no-href menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-82"><a href="#">Multimédia</a>
        <ul  class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-135" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://foo.bar">Photos &#038; vidéos</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="http://foo.bar">Téléchargements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-124"><a href="http://foo.bar">Arbitrage</a></li>
    <li class="sub__cat standalone el--right menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-132"><a href="http://foo.bar">Enseignement</a></li>
    <li class="sub__cat last__right el--right no-href menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-82"><a href="#">Multimédia</a>
        <ul  class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-135"><a href="http://foo.bar">Photos &#038; vidéos</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="http://foo.bar">Téléchargements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

If anyone have a clue about what is going on, I'll be very grateful.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think there is same code somewhere else .

Comment: check value of `jq('.el--right').length`

Comment: Checked number of "el--right" elements as you suggested, and bingo, some were hiding in the footer, for some reasons. I feel really really ashamed not having checked it before.

Anyways thank you very much !

Comment: glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some code with same **"el--right"** class were hiding in the footer, resulting in "grabbing" it to the menu and being wrapped with other **el--right** elements.

Thank you Pranav for the head-up.

Answer (score 0):

It won't duplicate elements but it will select all elements with the same class so check your HTML for the duplicates of the elements and handle it as you want.